# SQL SELECT Query Sum > Average

Tags: sql, ms-access

Need help on writing query to select all fields where field_value > average of that fields value. eg:

```
SELECT * WHERE NumWords > "Average of total numwords" FROM tblAdverts;
```

I tried this query but had no luck:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblAdverts
WHERE NumWords >(SUM(NumWords/COUNT(AdID)));
```

Comment: Hint:  Use a subquery in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblAdverts WHERE NumWords >(SELECT AVG(NumWords) FROM tblAdverts)
```